# Where should I place application specific directives with ngBoilerplate?

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

With **[ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp)**, where should I place and how should I structure my application wide filters, services and directives?

### src/app

The `app` directory seems to be arranged around routing.

> Apart from `app.js` and its accompanying tests (discussed below), this directory is filled with subdirectories corresponding to high-level sections of the application, often corresponding to top-level routes.

This is not the case, these do not correspond to a high-level section of the application, let alone to routes.

---

### src/common

There is also a `common` directory however. The `README.md` states:

> The `src/common/` directory houses internal and third-party re-usable
>   components. Essentially, this folder is for everything that isn't completely specific to this application.
>
> Every component contained here should be drag-and-drop reusable in any other project; they should depend on no other components that aren't similarly drag-and-drop reusable.

Which doesn't seem to apply in my case, as these items **are** specific to this application and wouldn't work in other apps.

*(Edited to address the src/common folder)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its application wide, you would put filters, services, and directives in the common folder.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but according to the README, I shouldn't place them here. (See updated question.)

Comment: Angular app structure is pretty open to discussion, and really should be what works for you and your team. I generally like to organize the code by features. So if you have a form, it would have its own folder containing related directives, services, controller, etc.